# How do I parse an HTML properly in R?

Tags: html, r, parsing, xpath, web-scraping

I have run into some problems parsing an html document. I use xml2 and so far I'm fairly happy. But there are still some hiccups I would like to solve. This is how I basically parse my documents:

```
html.raw <- xml2::read_html('/Users/simgeh/Documents/pipeDirs/BMAS/html_withid/2014_02_17_nahles_in_paris.html')        
docContent <- xml_text(xml_find_all(html.raw, xpath="//div[@id='content']//text()
                                        [not(ancestor-or-self::div[@class='docType'])]
                                        [not(ancestor-or-self::h1[@class='isFirstInSlot'])]
                                        [not(ancestor-or-self::div[@class='abstract'])]
                                        [not(ancestor-or-self::div[@class='sectionRelated'])]
                                        [not(ancestor-or-self::div[@id='contentsocial'])]"))
```

In most cases getting the content (mostly a longer text) works ok. But in some cases, for example when an article has some links put into the text, it can look like a mess. A parsed text should look like this:

> Am Donnerstag (12.01.) wird Bundesaußenminister Dr. Frank-Walter
>   Steinmeier im Auswärtigen Amt mit seinen Amtskollegen aus
>   Großbritannien und aus Frankreich, Jack Straw und Philippe
>   Douste-Blazy, sowie dem Hohen Repräsentanten der EU für die Gemeinsame
>   Außen- und Sicherheitspolitik, Javier Solana, zusammenkommen. Thema
>   des Treffens wird das iranische Nuklearprogramm sein.

but looks like this:

> Am Donnerstag (12.01.) wird Bundesaußenminister Dr. Frank-Walter
>   Steinmeier im Auswärtigen Amt mit seinen Amtskollegen aus
>   Großbritannien und aus Frankreich,
>
> Jack Straw
>
> und
>
> Philippe Douste-Blazy
>
> , sowie dem Hohen Repräsentanten der EU für die Gemeinsame Außen- und
>   Sicherheitspolitik,
>
> Javier Solana
>
> , zusammenkommen. Thema des Treffens wird das iranische
>   Nuklearprogramm sein.

The problem is that inside the text there are some words written in a different language and the author liked to indicate that. For example the name "Jack Straw" is referenced as follows:

```
<span lang=\"en-GB\" xml:lang=\"en-GB\" xml:lang=\"en-GB\">Jack Straw</span>
```

Everytime this happens the text gets messed up. So I am looking for some ways to improve the quality of the parsed text.

I maybe found a solution but it doesn't work as well as hoped. If I remove the `//text()` from my xpath string, the parsed text looks as good as intentioned but there is no way to remove undesired content from the container. In short `[not(ancestor-or-self` does not work which leaves the text cluttered with data I don't want.

A "short" illustration of my Problem:

```
<html>
# a lot of html before my node I want to grab...
 <div class="Pressemitteilungen">
   <div class="doctype">unwanted</div>
   <h1 class="something">unwanted</h1>
   <p>wanted data</p> 
   <p>wanted data 
     <span lang=\"en-GB\" xml:lang=\"en-GB\" xml:lang=\"en-GB\">wanted data</span>
   </p>
   <p>wanted data</p>
   <blockquote>  
     <p>wanted data</p>
   </blockquote>
   <p class="msSomething">wanted data</p>
   <p class="msSomethingElse">wanted data</p>
   <ul>
     <li> wanted data</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 # a lot of stuff after my node I want to grab...
</html>
```

The reason why I grab a complete node, which contains some data I don't need, is that there is no real way of telling what kind of tags I can expect and therefore need to grab. Sometimes the data is wrapped in a `<p>`, in a `<p class="msSomething">` or a `<p class="msSomethingElse">` and some more. So I thought it would be easier to delete the unwanted stuff from the node rather than individually look for the correct tags. We also talk a lot of data. (30.000+)

Take this pressrelease for example: 
http://www.bmas.de/DE/Presse/Pressemitteilungen/2014/2014_02_13_arbeitnehmerfreizuegigkeit.html

Using your Idea I grab my data like this:

```
docContent <- xml_text(xml_find_all(html.raw, xpath="(//div[@class='article-text singleview']//p[@class='MsoNormal']|
                                    //div[@class='article-text singleview']//h2|
                                    //div[@class='article-text singleview']//blockquote)//text()"))
```

As long as I still use `//text()` the text becomes messed up like this:

> [18] "\nMinister Hasan Ademov:"
>   [19] "Die bulgarische Regierung hat sich immer für die vollständige
>   Anwendung der "
>   [20] "EU"
>   [21] "-Rechtsvorschriften zur Arbeitnehmerfreizügigkeit ausgesprochen.
>   Unsere Position stimmt mit der des Europäischen Parlaments und der "
>   [22] "EU"
>   [23] "-Kommission überein – auch wir schätzen die Vorteile der
>   Freizügigkeit und ihre positive Auswirkung auf die Wirtschaft
>   innerhalb der "
>   [24] "EU"
>   [25] ". Gleichzeitig anerkennen wir, dass mit Rechten auch immer
>   entsprechende Pflichten verbunden sind. "

The reason for this are annotations like this `<abbr title="Europäische Union">EU</abbr>` within the text. When I remove `//text()` from xpath the text is perfectly structured but I can't remove unwanted data like this: (`[not(ancestor-or-self::div[@class='sectionRelated'])]`)

So, any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible? E.g. you could add a line like `html.raw <- xml2::read_html("<html>MINIMAL EXAMPLE HERE</html>"` containing the minimum number of lines which generate the *un*desired output, as well as an example of your desired output.

Comment: I added the basic structure of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

%%%%%% Iteration=1: not successful (yet)

Given the messiness of your html data, I suspect that we shall have to come to the solution with an iterative way, so here is my 1st shot:

```
library(xml2)

html.raw <- xml2::read_html('<html>
# a lot of html before my node I want to grab...
 <div class="Pressemitteilungen">
   <div class="doctype">unwanted 1</div>
   <h1 class="something">unwanted 2</h1>
   <p>wanted data 1</p> 
   <p>wanted data 2</p>
   <p>wanted data 3</p>
   <blockquote>  
     <p>wanted data 4</p>
   </blockquote>
   <p class="msSomething">wanted data 5</p>
   <p class="msSomethingElse">wanted data 6</p>
   <ul>
     <li> wanted data 7</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 # a lot of stuff after my node I want to grab...
</html>')

print(docContent <- xml_text(xml_find_all(html.raw, xpath="(//p|//li)//text()")))
```

Now if your document contains more "wanted data" within other tags, or possibly even "unwanted data" within some the *same tags* as the "wanted data", then please update your minimal example with relevant cases and we take it from there.

%%%%%% Iteration=2: getting closer :D

For the specific press release that you just linked, using a single backslash before `p`, `h2` and `blockquote` (and removing the problematic `//text()`) produces what I believe is your desired outcome (I still have to try and guess what you actually want), because the unwanted `h2` tags "Audio" and "Weitere Informationen" are enclosed within a further `<div class="sectionRelated">`:

```
xpath <- "(//div[@class='article-text singleview']/p[@class='MsoNormal']|
           //div[@class='article-text singleview']/h2|
           //div[@class='article-text singleview']/blockquote)"
docContent <- xml_text(xml_find_all(html.raw, xpath=xpath))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still got the problem, that the text is cluttered when I apply `text()`.

Comment: How does the cluttering appear in your own example?

Comment: You can see the cluttering in the two blockquote boxes above. I also described what might cause it although I have no idea why...

Comment: I don't have the data of your two blockquote boxes above, so I cannot reproduce the problem. If I cannot reproduce the problem, I cannot fix it. The only data I have is the "short" illustration of your Problem; so could you please indicate me what exactly goes wrong in my treatment of your "short illustration", or post the data for the two blockquotes above?

Comment: Added some additional information the article. Thank you for your patience :)